# How to make a ball hit many tiled circular objects in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, box2d

Hey guys I've been learning to make games with LibGDX. I did a tiled map in Tiled and the rest of code in java using Android Studio. I could make a ball bounce on the flour using Box2D, but I can't make this same ball hit some circular or elliptcal objects from certain Tiled's layer. I've been searching for days, but I'm very newbee to this and I can't understand the explanations the figure this out.

What happens when I click run:

It's showing the the ball image falling next to a circular shape (I think it's made by debug renderer) and the tiled image is shown, but the ball doesn't collide. The ball passes through and nothing happens. I can't see any circular shapes near the tiled image. Maybe the problem is in my for in the code below.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyBallGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    World world;
    Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
    OrthographicCamera cam;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture ball;
    Texture bg;
    Body body;
    Body circulo;
    Sprite sprite;
    //TILES
    //private TmxMapLoader maploader;
    private TiledMap map;
    private TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;
    //private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        //TILES
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        cam.update();

        map = new TmxMapLoader().load("tiles.tmx");
        tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
        world = new World(new Vector2(0, -980), true);
        debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        ball = new Texture("circulo.png");
        sprite = new Sprite(ball);
        // Center the sprite in the top/middle of the screen
        sprite.setPosition(100, 400);

        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY());
        // Create a body in the world using our definition
        body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        // Create a circle shape and set its radius to 6
        CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
        circle.setRadius(6f);
// Create a fixture definition to apply our shape to
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = circle;
        fixtureDef.density = 1.5f;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.4f;
        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.6f; // Make it bounce a little bit
// Create our fixture and attach it to the body
        Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

        circle.dispose();
//Tiled objects:
        BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
        //PolygonShape pshape = new PolygonShape();
        FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();

        for(MapObject object : map.getLayers().get(1).getObjects().getByType(CircleMapObject.class)){
            Circle circ = ((CircleMapObject) object).getCircle();

            bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
            bdef.position.set(0, 0);

            circulo = world.createBody(bdef);
            CircleShape cShape = new CircleShape();
            cShape.setRadius(circ.radius);
            //pshape.setRadius(circ.radius);
            //fdef.shape = pshape;
            fixtureDef.shape = cShape;
            fixtureDef.density = 1.5f;

            body.createFixture(fdef);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        // Advance the world, by the amount of time that has elapsed since the
        //last frame
        // Generally in a real game, dont do this in the render loop, as you are
        //tying the physics
        // update rate to the frame rate, and vice versa
        world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 6, 2);

        // Now update the spritee position accordingly to it's now updated
        //Physics body
        sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y);

        // You know the rest...
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        //TILES
        cam.update();
        tiledMapRenderer.setView(cam);
        tiledMapRenderer.render();
        debugRenderer.render(world, cam.combined);


        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(sprite, sprite.getX(), sprite.getY());
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it's failing. Is the debug rendering showing the bodies in the positions you expect them to be?

Comment: A couple of screenshots would be helpful. A gif would be ideal. One handy tool for gif creation is [Licecap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same Problem with my game and i watch a tutorial series on youtube from Brent Aureli. He is explaining this really well i will put a link right here. Maybe it will help you as well .

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcH6Mp03KC0

Edit: Have you set the CategoryBits? like that

```
public static final short NOTHING_BIT = 0;
public static final short GROUND_BIT = 1;
public static final short LINK_BIT = 2;
public static final short BRICK_BIT = 4;
public static final short STONE_BIT = 8;
```

and then you need to write these lines of code for each object you create so that the categorybits can collide with each other:

```
fdef.filter.categoryBits = GetTheTriforce.LINK_BIT;
fdef.filter.maskBits = GetTheTriforce.GROUND_BIT |
            GetTheTriforce.STONE_BIT |
            GetTheTriforce.BRICK_BIT |
            GetTheTriforce.ENEMY_BIT |
            GetTheTriforce.OBJECT_BIT |
            GetTheTriforce.ENEMY_HEAD_BIT |
            GetTheTriforce.ITEM_BIT|
            GetTheTriforce.END_BIT|
            GetTheTriforce.HOLE_BIT;
```

so that the whole code should something like that:

```
BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    bdef.position.set(currentPosition.add(0, 10 / GetTheTriforce.PPM));
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    b2body = world.createBody(bdef);

    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(6 / GetTheTriforce.PPM);
    fdef.filter.categoryBits = GetTheTriforce.LINK_BIT;
    fdef.filter.maskBits = GetTheTriforce.GROUND_BIT |
            GetTheTriforce.STONE_BIT |
            GetTheTriforce.BRICK_BIT |
            GetTheTriforce.ENEMY_BIT |
            GetTheTriforce.OBJECT_BIT |
            GetTheTriforce.ENEMY_HEAD_BIT |
            GetTheTriforce.ITEM_BIT|
            GetTheTriforce.END_BIT|
            GetTheTriforce.HOLE_BIT;

    fdef.shape = shape;
    b2body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData(this);
    shape.setPosition(new Vector2(0, -14 / GetTheTriforce.PPM));
    b2body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData(this);
```

thats just some of the code i used in my game

Comment: Bexx, I watched the same tutorial too. I did the for loop like Brent Aureli did, but my objecst are circurcles (or ellipses, i'm not sure), so maybe that's the problem. I think I didn't get the objects. I don't know what classes and methods to use.

Comment: just edited my answer maybe it helps.
is this the only code you are using or are there more classes? and whats the general idea behind the game

Comment: Thanks Bexx, I'm using just 1 class. I made some confusion. I thought the link was to another video that Brent made earlier in the same series about Mario Bros. Since my game is even more simple, I think I figured out how to do the collisions just repeating a sprite with for loop, so I dont need the map. Although, your answer well be very good for me to learn to lead with collisions with tiled objects when I need it!